# node express order routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have my routes setup like that:

```
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/auth', auth);
app.use(RequestHandlers.Authorize);    
app.post('/users', users);    
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(RequestHandlers.NotFound);
```

My handlers:

```
export function Authorize(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {

    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
    //token logic
  };

export function NotFound(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
    var err: any = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
  }
```

So I have no problems to handle any defined routes but when I am accessing any not existed routes the `RequestHandlers.Authorize` always getting executed first. But if the route is not existed I want to fire `app.use(RequestHandlers.NotFound);`

How can I do that? What is the best approach without putting much custom logic on the routes? May be there is the way to check if route is defined?

Comment: you can get all routes that are defined by `app._router.stack`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `app.use(fn)` you're saying "use this middleware function for *every* request".

Seeing as you only want the `authorize` function to run on specific routes, you should add it to only those routes, using the following method:

```
app.get('/', middleware, fn)
```

…so for your specific example:

```
app.get('/', RequestHandlers.Authorize, index)
app.get('/users', RequestHandlers.Authorize, users)
```

The `middleware` argument when creating a route can be a `function (req, res, next)` or it can be an array of functions.

More info here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-handlers